# Can you recover a spacetime from its null geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, causality, geodesics

So, I know that you can learn a lot about a spacetime from its causal structure, but can one completely recover the metric of a spacetime, just knowing the equations for the null geodesics in it?

If so, how would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only recover conformally related spacetimes from its null geodesics, that is, the class of spacetimes related by the transformation

$g_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow \Omega^2(x) g_{\mu\nu}$

which possess a different matter content

Comment: This is interesting. Is there a good source where I can read more?

Comment: Check Hawking/Ellis pp.60--61 and Wald, p.445. Cheers.